# A baseball player hits the ball 35% of the time. In 10 opportunities, what is the probability of connecting more than 2 hits?

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, binomial-distribution

[FORMULAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbXTi.png)A baseball player hits the ball 35% of the time. In 10 opportunities, what is the probability of connecting more than 2 hits?

What is the expected value of the number of hits in 10 chances?

What is the standard deviation?

Comment: 0.35(1-0.035)/10 (than square root) which gave me =0.15  for standard deviation

Comment: Why do you divide by 10?  Which formula are you applying?  (Also, note that $0.035$ is probably a typo.)

Comment: yes that was a typo and because it's out of 10 chances.

Comment: Intuitively, the larger the number of opportunities, the greater will be the standard deviation.  If our baseball player only has one attempt, the number of hits is either $0$ or $1$, but for $10$ attempts, the number of hits is between $0$ and $10$ and, if the experiment is repeated many times, there is going to be more spread if each experiment consists of $10$ attempts than if it consists of only $1$.  Check your source for the formula of the standard deviation.  You may also find the formula of the expected value next to it.

Comment: I added my formula sheet

Comment: Yes, Chapter 6 has the right formula.  Follow gt6989b's advice and answer the question, "Which distribution are we dealing with here?"

Answer (score 0):

You are making $10$ yes-or-no experiments, assuming they are all independent with the same probability of success $p = 0.35$. Your random variable is the number of successes in those attempts.

- Which distribution does it follow?
- To compute probability of more than 2, you may want to compute the probability of less than or equal to 2.